# Remove first word from a <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my page and i want to remove first word and the minus with java script or jquery(in this case #123456 -)

```
<td id="someid"><a>#123456 - Some Text</a></td>
```

to look like this

```
<td id="someid"><a>Some Text</a></td>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to post your attempted solution as part of your question: what you tried to do, what you expected that code to do, what it did instead/what it did wrong. Please, take a read of both the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Comment: Is the `-` always present in the text? If so `split()` by that character and use the second value in the resulting array

Comment: `$('#someid a').text($('#someid a').text().trim().split('-')[1].trim())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using jQuery

```
var col = $('#someid').html();
var anchor= col;
$('#someid').html('<a>'+anchor.split('-')[1].split('<')[0]+'</a>')
```

find the working fiddle example. https://jsfiddle.net/957keh1q/1/

Comment: I am glad I am able too assist you.

Answer (score 2):

Using str.substring split your string from the index of

'-' + 2 = Start of Second word to length of string

```js
var str = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML;
newstr = str.substring(str.indexOf('-')+2, str.length); 
console.log(newstr);
```

```html
<td id="someid"><a>#123456 - Some Text</a></td>
```

Comment: Please take the time to explain your code, that way the OP - and future visitors - might learn something useful and broadly applicable from your answer, rather than just black-box code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = $("#someid a").html();
$("#someid a").html( str.substring(str.search("-")+1, str.length));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someid"><a>#123456 - Some Text</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "-" char is fixed, split the string in two

```
var txtArray = $('#someid').val.split("-");
```

and take out the first space:

```
var newText = txtArray[txtArray.length - 1].trim();
```

Comment: `$('#someid').val.split` totally wrong .. `.val()` needs `()` if input or textarea .. and in this case `.text()`